# TPL Dataflow Complete Pipeline when condition matches

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, pipeline, tpl-dataflow, bufferblock

I thought it's very basic approach but I haven't found any example yet.
I have one producer and one consumer and I want to finish the pipeline when at least x objects were processed. Additionally I need to know what objects have been received.

That's how I do it:

```
public class BlockTester
{
    private static TransformBlock<int, int> _worker;

    public static async Task StartAsync()
    {
        _worker = new TransformBlock<int, int>(s => s + s);
        var buffer = new BufferBlock<int>();
        var consumeTask = Consume(buffer);

        _worker.LinkTo(buffer, new DataflowLinkOptions{PropagateCompletion = true});

        foreach (var value in Enumerable.Range(0,100))
        {
            _worker.Post(value);
        }

        _worker.Complete();

        await buffer.Completion;

        if(buffer.TryReceiveAll(out var received))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", received));
        }
    }

    public static async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<int>> Consume(ISourceBlock<int> buffer)
    {
        var received = new List<int>();

        while (await buffer.OutputAvailableAsync())
        {
            var current = buffer.Receive();

            received.Add(current);

            if (current > 25)
            {
                _worker.Complete();
            }
        }

        return received;
    }
}
```

I am a bit confused about the buffer.TryReceiveAll. What's the difference between awaiting the consume task and the TryReceiveAll? Why does TryReceiveAll is false in my scenario? I guess there's still something wrong with my approach to reach my goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Consume` method should be an `ActionBlock`. There's no need to use `OutputAvailableAsync` or `TryRecieveAll`. Replace the `BufferBlock` with an `ActionBlock` and do your processing within the `ActionBlock`. It's not clear why you would need the `TransformBlock` either unless you have more than one step in the process.

```
public class BlockTester
{
    //Could be removed
    private static TransformBlock<int, int> _worker;

    public static async Task StartAsync()
    {
        //Could be removed
        _worker = new TransformBlock<int, int>(s => s + s);
        var processor = new ActionBlock<int>(x => ProcessMessage(x));

        _worker.LinkTo(processor, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

        foreach (var value in Enumerable.Range(0, 100))
        {
            _worker.Post(value);
        }

        //_worker.Complete();

        await processor.Completion;
    }


    private static int itemsRecieved = 0;
    public static void ProcessMessage(int x)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref itemsRecieved);
        if (itemsRecieved > 25) _worker.Complete();
        //process the message
        //log the message etc.
    }
}
```

Or with a complex message object:

```
public class Message { }

public class BlockTester
{
    //Could be removed
    private static TransformBlock<Message, Message> _worker;

    public static async Task StartAsync()
    {
        //Could be removed
        _worker = new TransformBlock<Message, Message>(s => s);
        var processor = new ActionBlock<Message>(x => ProcessMessage(x));

        _worker.LinkTo(processor, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

        foreach (var value in Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(_ => new Message()))
        {
            _worker.Post(value);
        }

        //_worker.Complete();

        await processor.Completion;
    }


    private static ConcurrentBag<Message> itemsRecieved = new ConcurrentBag<Message>();
    public static void ProcessMessage(Message x)
    {
        itemsRecieved.Add(x);
        if (itemsRecieved.Count > 25) _worker.Complete();
        //process the message
        //log the message etc.
    }
}
```

**Edit**
To answer the original question:

> Why does `TryReceiveAll` return false:

Because by the time `TryReceiveAll` is ran the `BufferBlock` has "completed". For a block to be completed it must contain 0 items in its output buffer. The `Consume` method was pulling all the items out before the block was allowed to complete and you'd finally call `TryRecieveAll` on an empty block.

Comment: Yes the example is simplified. I have an I/O Task in the TransformBlock and the Consume-Block is a "do a summary block". Your approach with Interlocked.Increment maybe works for primitive objects but I want to collect reference objects and print them at the end of the pipeline.

Comment: You can collect objects in a `ConcurrentBag` if you need access from multiple threads but with default block options you could use a simple list.

Comment: I got some more thoughts. So that's the way to go? Adding an ActionBlock which "posts" the items to a ConcurrencyBag? Edit: Haha, same thoughts ;)

Comment: It's a reasonable option for your requirements. But I have limited view of what you really trying to accomplish. That being said dataflow will do a lot for you out of the box when you have a simple pipeline structure, that's where it excels.

Comment: I think I'll use your approach. Could you update the ´Interlocked.Increment(ref itemsRecieved);´ to an ConcurrentBag to collect the objects, then I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: @BlackMatrix Done

Comment: JSteward  Thanks
Could you also explain why TryReceiveAll is false in my initial case?

Comment: Because by the time you run that code the `BufferBlock` has "completed". For a block to be completed it must contain 0 items in its output buffer. Your `Consume` method was pulling all the items out before the block was allowed to complete and you'd finally call `TryRecieveAll` on an empty block. (Added explanation to main answer for readers)

Comment: ProcessMessage contains at least one race condition, since adding to items received and getting the count are not atomic.